# Attempting to pause setinterval for 10 seconds when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval, clearinterval

I am attempting to temporarily pause a `setInterval` when the "next" button is clicked. Currently it stops the current setinterval but doesn't start it again after 10 seconds.

I have a simple image rotator that changes the image ever 4 seconds. When the "Next" button is clicked I want it to pause the interval for 10 seconds before starting the 4 second rotation again.

Heres the code so far (has been simplified):

```
var ic = $('#imageContainer');
var numItems = $('.image').size();
var position = 0;
ic.css('left', '0px');

var inter;

function rotate() {
    inter = setInterval(function () {
        if (position == (numItems - 1)) {
            console.log(position);
            $('.image').first().insertAfter($('.image').last());
            ic.css('left', '+=400px');
            position--;
        }
        ic.animate({
            left: "-=400px"
        });
        position += 1;
    }, 4000);
}
rotate();

$('#next').click(function () {
    clearInterval(inter);
    nextInter = setInterval(function () {
        rotate();
    }, 10000);
    clearInterval(nextInter);
});
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why you mix **animate** and **insert**?

Comment: issues like this are a good example of why a self-firing `setTimeout` is usually better than `setInterval`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because you are clearing the `nextInter` just one line after you've created it.

```
nextInter = setInterval(function(){rotate();}, 10000 );
clearInterval(nextInter);
```

However, if you remove the last `clearInterval`, your `nextInter` interval will call `rotate` every 10 seconds, that will set a new interval for every 4 seconds. This certainly will cause unexpected behavior. I think you are looking for `setTimeout` instead.

```
$('#next').click(function () {
    clearInterval(inter);
    setTimeout(rotate, 10000);
});
```

Also, if you want to prevent from doing multiple `rotate`s if you click the next button multiple times, you could create a variable outside your callback scope to store your `setTimeout` instance and then clear it when the button is clicked. Example:

```
var rotateTimeout;
$('#next').click(function () {
    clearInterval(inter);
    clearTimeout(rotateTimeout);
    rotateTimeout = setTimeout(rotate, 10000);
});
```

Comment: How do I prevent it doing multiple `rotate`s if I click the next button multiple times during the 10 second timeout? heres an example: http://chrismepham.com/sites/test/livesearch.html

Comment: Edited the answer to regard your question.

Answer (score 3):

After scheduling the `nextInter`, you are clearing it soon after it is executed.

What you need here is [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout) instead of [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval). What you need was to call rotate after 10 seconds but setInterval will call it in every 10 seconds so you were clearing it but the problem was you were clearing it before it had a chance to execute rotate even once.

```
$('#next').click(function () {
    clearInterval(inter);
    setTimeout(rotate, 10000 );
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout):

```
$('#next').click(function () {
    clearInterval(inter);
    nextInter = setTimeout(rotate, 10000);
});
```